# CPU usage is 100% because of svchost.exe windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, cpu, process-explorer, svchost

It has been a while now since my laptop started being very slow and cpu usage is 100% almost all the time. I downloaded process monitor and below is the process details that is taking most of the usage. I'd really appreciate it if anyone could please advise how to fix this as it is really annoying.

[image]

Comment: You'll need to find out which service is misbehaving. A good start is to disable the service you have last installed / enabled and see if that helps.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev The screenshot in my question shows the list of the services attached to the process that is consuming most of the CPU usage.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is quite impossible for me to tell which service causes trouble by merely looking at the list.

Comment: but I don't understand, like if this process is the one consuming all the CPU usage and these are the services attached to it, then what else should be causing problem? and how to know which services cause the trouble?

Comment: There is a good chance you have identified the *process* causing the problem, so there's nothing else that might be causing it. Unfortunately, you can't just disable all the listed services (you're most probably using some of them), so you'll have to identify the *service* causing trouble.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev but how to identify the service causing the trouble?

Comment: Many of those services could indeed be termporarily stopped, in the services section >%windir%\system32\services.msc  Call me lasy but it would be fairly fast to observe CPU use, and stop (temporarily) some of them discluding the event logger (sens) which can cause high cpu use by stopping it, or it not working properly. Most of them would cry about it if they were doing something important at the time, and it indeed could stop a program from doing something, and it would not finish properly.  So while it could cause a problem, I would do it anyway. (Stop is not to suggest disable).

Comment: capture a xperf trace and share it: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would proceed by disabling some of services listed on your screenshot to identify the culprit. Problem is, there are services which are essential for normal operation, and disabling them might cause you a lot of trouble (e.g. if you disable Group Policy Client or User Profile Service you may not be able to login anymore).

If you have an idea on which service have been installed / enabled recently, you should start by disabling it. Otherwise, I'd try to disable "Server" and "Internet connection sharing" to see if that helps.

It may so happen that you actually need those services so you cant't just keep them disabled. However, if you can prove that they are the source of the problem, your question will become much more specific and answerable.

Comment: I've tried stopping both the `server` and `internet connection sharing` but it gives me this error message when trying to do so `error opening service for control: Access is denied`

Comment: Do you have admin rights on your PC? Are there group policies preventing service management by local users? Is there an IT department in charge of your PC, or do you own it?

Comment: @Shepherd Those should be easy to stop, with admin powers .  In fact those 2 will not effect booting unless you are somehow oddly dependant on a net  , so they can be disabled, without booting issues.  (reboot would be required after disable, to complete)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, svchhost.exe is the parent process to a group of windows services. This one seems to run many network services. 
You should look for massive/unwanted network traffic. A good start would be [Microsoft Message Analyser](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226)

Comment: as stated in my question this is the process that is consuming almost all the CPU usage.

Comment: @shepherd If there is heavy traffic generated by the services, the parent svchost.exe will take a lot of CPU time.